# Displaying youtube video in portrait with the YouTubeStandalonePlayer

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

With the new `youtube api` for android, when trying to start an activity with the  **[YouTubeStandalonePlayer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer)**  it displays the video on landscape mode.

```
Intent youtubeIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(context, Configuration.DEVELOPER_KEY, item.getVideo().getId(), 0, true,false);
context.startActivity(youtubeIntent);
```

I want the video still to be displayed on full screen but with portrait mode.

Comment: Its been 2 years since this question was asked, but unfortunately there's still no solution available!

Comment: another year passed, any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try setting the `lightboxMode` parameter (the last boolean) to true. It won't be fullscreen then, but I think it might stay in portrait mode at least (I think, haven't tried it though...).

Comment: I know, but I still want it to be full screen :\

Comment: that's not possible with the current API :(

Comment: it's the closest to what I need, but still not complete, as long as there content on background